# flutter firestore query many to many related data

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can i display the groupnames (and data) of a user as a list stream? there are many tutorials for streambuilders  for collections directly containing the data. But what is common if the Ids of the subcollection fist have to be fetched?

The db has two collections, users and groups:

users:
[user collection with userIds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT7fl.png)

users-subcollection:
[users-subcollection with groupIds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS2Zm.png)

groups:
[groups collection with group data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twpak.png)

groups-subcollection:
[groups-subcollection with memberIds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14Kl0.png)

My approach was a ListView with stream

```
Stream<<List<groupId>> streamGroupId(String userId) => _db
  .collection("users").doc(groupId).collection("groups")
  .snapshots()
  .map((snapshot) =>
      snapshot.docs.map((doc) => GroupId.fromFirestore(doc)).toList());
```

and every child contains another stream to get the groupdata:

```
  Stream<Group> streamGroups(String groupId) => _db
  .collection("groups").doc(groupId)
  .snapshots()
  .map((snapshot) =>
      snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Group.fromFirestore(doc)));
```

Is it save to open so many streams? Is there a simpler way to display this ListView?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it save to open so many streams?

Safety is about firestore rules not the listener you add, But be aware that limit of snapshot listeners per client is under 100.